# Curved line between two points. Android

Tags: java, android, line, android-canvas

How i can draw that line with changeable angle and direction?
[image: example of line]

Red - it is points.

Answer (score 0):

Check out

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html

It has a `drawArc()` method which you might find useful.